# Why JQuery return Undefined when try to catch value from input type text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function testFunction(){
            var stringCode =  '#abc[0][0]';
            console.log(stringCode);
            result = $(stringCode).val();
            console.log(result);
        }   
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="abc[0][0]" value="5" readonly="true/">
<input type="button" onClick="testFunction()"/>

</body>

</html>
```

My Main problem is-

When i click the button and look to browser console so i get undefined
as result of console.log(result). How to fix it so the code can show 5
as the result not undefined ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is "abc" supposed to do?

Comment: What is `abc` in your dom

Comment: @eric-guan : sorry for my typo, i already update my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below (In jquery which is used in your code):-

```js
function testFunction(){
  result = $('input[id ="abc[0][0]"]').val();
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="abc[0][0]" value="5" readonly="true/">
<input type="button" onClick="testFunction()" value = "ClickMe!"/>

</body>

</html>
```

Note:-

This is called `[attribute=value]` selector

[Check all available different selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If things are simple then try simple way

```js
function testFunction(){
  var f = document.getElementById("abc[0][0]");
  result = f.value;
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<input type="hidden" id="abc[0][0]" value="5" readonly="true/">
<input type="button" onClick="testFunction()" value = "ClickMe!"/>

</body>

</html>
```